# Plot an oscillator line on price

Tags: pine-script

I have an oscilator in the bottom pane of a chart and want to plot lines when certain conditions are met on the price pane. Is there any way to do this in pine-script?

Comment: Could be possible but need more information. What kind of oscillator is that? Where do you want to plot lines? What are your conditions?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing a script not running with [`overlay=true`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_study) can do on a chart is color bars using [`barcolor()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_barcolor).

A workaround is to use two different copies of the script: one running in the pane as usual, and the other one in overlay mode, so that it can place objects on the chart.